# Python - Close all active documents without saving

Tags: python, python-3.x, photoshop, win32com

I need to close all Photoshop documents, be it any number, without saving and without any user prompt. My current code is below for closing the active document only.

```
psApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Photoshop.Application")
psApp.Application.ActiveDocument.Close(2) # close file without saving
psApp.Quit()
```

Photoshops API documentation is terrible, but here's what I've attempted for closing all:

```
while psApp.documents.length:
    psApp.activeDocument.close()

AttributeError: <unknown>.length
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
while True:
    try:
        psApp.Application.ActiveDocument.Close(2)
    except:
        break
psApp.Quit()
```

I dont have PS, but I can confirm it works with Word!

Answer (score 0):

I can close all active documents with this.

```
while psApp.Documents.Count > 0:
    psApp.ActiveDocument.Close(2)
```